# New sympy intersection usage

Tags: python, sympy

Up to version 1.3, this code worked well:

```
from sympy import Intersection; 
from sympy import solveset; 
from sympy import S; from sympy.abc import x; 
from sympy.functions.elementary.miscellaneous import Min, Max; 
print Intersection([solveset(p, x, S.Reals) for p in [((((x + 2.0000) * 3.0000)+18.000000) > 0.000), ((((x + 2.0000) * 3.0000)+18.000000) < 1.000)]])
```

I don't know how to use the new `Intersection`, c.f. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: I have to unpack the argument to `Intersection` with the `*`-operator:

```
print Intersection(*[solveset(p, x, S.Reals) for p in [((((x + 2.0000) * 3.0000)+18.000000) > 0.000), ((((x + 2.0000) * 3.0000)+18.000000) < 1.000)]])
```